# How to handle Upper case request payload in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, jax-rs

For example my payload will be like following. How to consume this payload and bind it to entity. I know that jackson-dataformat-xml can handle normal xml payload.

```
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <AddRecipient>
      <LIST_ID>12345</LIST_ID>
      <CREATED_FROM>1</CREATED_FROM>
      <UPDATE_IF_FOUND>true</UPDATE_IF_FOUND>
      <COLUMN>
        <NAME>EMAIL</NAME>
        <VALUE>someone@domain.com</VALUE>
      </COLUMN>
    </AddRecipient>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: I want the above payload to bind my java object and wants to use that to call another web service using RestTemplate

Comment: You can achieve using Jaxb by providing @XmlElement("YOUR_ELEMENT_NAME-CAPS") something like this.

Comment: Well, what about that Envelope and Body tags. How to handle them?

Comment: I'm referring to the following https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/create-springboot-xml-rest-service

Comment: It's just about creating POJOs with the nesting to match the the xml and annotate accordingly with `@XmlElement` and `@XmlRootElement`.

Comment: You mean to say that i have to create a class called Envelope and another called Body ?

Comment: For you to understand easily, create a class Envelope with a field body of type Body. The Body class has field addRecipient of type AddRecipient. The class AddRecipient has fields listId and so on. Annotate the classes with `@XmlRootElement` and the fields with `@XmlElement` with the names between quotes exactly same as in the xml.

Comment: Got it. I want that above xml payload to be given to an another endpoint. is there any way to get the same payload. So that i can pass it.

Comment: Better way is to receive that xml payload as string and give it to an another rest endpoint using Rest Template. But i want that Request contract to be defined as Entity

Comment: What does the endpoint that you're trying to send the payload accept? Xml or json or text?

Comment: Its xml format..

Comment: Use the same object as I told earlier. While using resttemplate, add HttpHeaders object with `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` and pass the object as the entity.

Comment: Okay. Thank You.